# How do I know when and where a static inline in-class-initialised member object is initialised?

Tags: c++, c++17, static-initialization

Before C++17 you needed to define and/or initialise a non-const class member object separately from the class definition, otherwise you got a linker error:

```
//MyClass.h
extern int globalInt;
class MyClass
{public:
      static int classStaticMemberInt;
};

//MyClass.cpp
int globalInt = 7;
int MyClass::classStaticMemberInt = globalInt;
```

Choosing this method I know that the MyClass::classStaticMemberInt object is initialised after the "int globalInt". It's defined only once, and I choose where to define it.

After C++17 we have the choice of avoiding writing everything twice, and just doing:

```
//MyClass.h
extern int globalInt;
class MyClass
{public:
     static inline classStaticMemberInt = globalInt;
}
```

But if I include the "MyClass.h" header in a few compilation units, and I want, for example, to be sure that "int globalInt" is initialised before int MyClass::classStaticMemberInt, how can I know? I imagine the static inline in-class syntax in C++17 essentially tells the compiler to define that variable/object once, "somewhere", but where is that somewhere? For example if I do the following:

```
// Some cpp
int globalInt = 7; // Global object definition
#include MyClass.h    // Include class MyClass, 
// which static inline defines classStaticMemberInt 
    //to be equal to "int globalInt"
```

Is the class member object guaranteed to have the right value because the preprocessor pastes the class definition after "int globalInt = 7;"?

Also, let's just say that I paste the "MyClass.h" header into another .cpp, because the compiler should 'define' that object only once in one translation unit does it mean that it can choose to define it in the .cpp that I didn't define the global object in? And therefore any care I take to paste the header after the global int definition is pointless?

Comment: In the first example, do you mean `static int a;`?

Comment: And if you depend on initialization order between translation units, then I'd argue your design is wrong. Why do you need `anotherObject` to be initialized before `MyClass::a`? What is the problem that's supposed to solve? What is the use-case?

Comment: In your example, both objects are zero-initialized at program startup before any code is executed ([**\[basic.start.static\]**](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static)), so the issue is moot.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If they're both zero initialised none of this matters. I changed the question a bit.

Comment: `globalInt` is constant-initialized at program startup before any code is executed, and so before `classStaticMemberInt` is initialized.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik OK, well let's assume that globalInt can't be statically initialised, like "int globalInt = rand();" In my pre-C++17 example globalInt guaranteed to be initialised before the class member, but what about initialised with post-C++17 static inline in-class initialiser?

Comment: Now we have to look at [**\[basic.start.dynamic\]**](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.dynamic). It tells us that a) the initialization of `classStaticMemberInt` is partially-ordered, b) that of `globalInt` is ordered, and c) roughly, ordered initializations are executed in order within the translation unit; partially-ordered are executed before other partially-ordered or ordered if the former appears before the latter in every translation unit that defines the latter; but otherwise, there is no order. So no, there's no guarantee that `classStaticMemberInt` be initialized before `globalInt`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik The trouble I'm having in understanding this is that if you have a header with class MyClass { static inline member; }; and #include that into 5 cpp files, it's defined once, somewhere, by the compiler, but I don't know where.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You seem to have understood it just fine. I fail to grasp the nature of your difficulty.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Because the objects are initialized in the order that they're defined, except when I do "static inline int staticMember;" in a header, and I paste it into a few cpps, that variable is 'defined' by the compiler in just one spot, and I don't know where it'll do that, and so I don't know if it'll be defined AFTER I define some other object, or indeed even if it'll be defined in the same cpp as the one I defined the other object in. Without the new syntax I'd define it manually and the in right order.

Comment: Yes, that's right. So, is there anything you still feel is unclear to you? Is there a question in there somewhere you'd like answered?